# copy target files from list of computers more elegantly

Tags: powershell, logging, naturallyspeaking

I collect logs from the top 50 computers to analyze user information of an application called Dragon, used to dictatate text.  The script I use to collect these logs I think could be much better.  Anyone care to share suggestion for improvment?  Point me in the right direction and I will do the rest.  Please find the code pasted below.

```
#copying ALL directories from c:\User\ recursively, and as many of the log files #as it finds.  Copies perhaps 100-1000 empty directories for every log file it finds.


$server_names = Get-Content "C:\powershell\Dragonlog\Log Grab\sept915920.txt"
Foreach ($server in $server_names){
Copy-Item \\$server\c$\Users C:\dgnlogs\top50915920\$Server -filter dragon.log -Recurse 

}

#robocopy to remove redundant empty directories. 

robocopy C:\dgnlogs\top50915920 C:\splunkdragonlogs\top50915920 /s /move
```

Comment: Hi! Stack Overflow is a Q&A site focusing on programming questions. Your question seems better suited for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe together commands

Get Content | Foreach Line Run Copy-Item

RoboCopy to Clean Up

```
Get-Content "C:\powershell\Dragonlog\Log Grab\sept915920.txt" | Copy-Item \\$_\c$\Users C:\dgnlogs\top50915920\$_ -filter dragon.log -Recurse
robocopy C:\dgnlogs\top50915920 C:\splunkdragonlogs\top50915920 /s /move
```